# Как реализовать аккордеон на QSS в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qss

Возможно ли в *Qt Designer* и *QSS* создать такой виджет, где будет расположено несколько элементов друг под другом, рядом с ними кнопки, 
а по нажатии на кнопку около соответствующего элемента под ним будет появляться фрейм с какой-либо информацией? 
При этом нижестоящие элементы сдвинутся вниз.

Это еще называется аккордеоном в кругах фронтенда.

Есть идея запрограммировать кнопку на сдвиг нижестоящих элементов на, например, 1000 пикселей и соответственно раскрыть (`hidden = false`) 
тот или иной фрейм. 
Но это кажется мне слишком костыльным...

Есть ли более простой способ реализации такой идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, в *Qt Designer* вы такого не сделаете.

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте код, который у вас уже написан.

Один из возможных вариантов, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QFormLayout,\
    QLineEdit, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QCheckBox, QApplication


class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.oldSize = None
        self.item = item
        
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow('Я label', QLineEdit(self))
        layout.addRow('Клик', QCheckBox(
            'Скрыть кнопку ниже', self, toggled=self.hideChild))
        self.button = QPushButton('Cпряч меня', self)
        layout.addRow(self.button)

    def hideChild(self, v):
        self.button.setVisible(not v)
        # Здесь важно: скрывая внутренние дочерние элементы управления, 
        # необходимо пересчитать высоту.
        self.adjustSize()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(CustomWidget, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.item.setSizeHint(QSize(self.minimumWidth(), self.height()))


class CustomButton(QPushButton):
    """ Кнопка как переключатель """

    def __init__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.item = item
        self.setCheckable(True)     

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(CustomButton, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.item.setSizeHint(QSize(self.minimumWidth(), self.height()))


class Window(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        for _ in range(7):
            # переключатель
            item = QListWidgetItem(self)
            btn = CustomButton(item, f'Folding {_+1}', self, objectName='testBtn')
            self.setItemWidget(item, btn)

            item = QListWidgetItem(self)
            # Скрыть/показать следующие пункты, нажав кнопку
            btn.toggled.connect(item.setHidden)
            self.setItemWidget(item, CustomWidget(item, self))
            btn.click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')       
    # Изменить высоту кнопки на qss
    app.setStyleSheet('#testBtn{min-height: 40px;}')
    w = Window()
    w.resize(300, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прощу прощения, снова забыл об этом, но кода не было как такового. Спасибо большое за ответ! На просторах интернета конкретики не слышал об этом, теперь вопрос точно закрыт.
А я может перейду к реализации задуманного в отдельных окнах.

Comment: @Regulirovshik пожалуйста.